# Cigarette lighter plug inside clip missing (Astra mk4)

Tags: electrical, repair

I recently got something stuck in my lighter plug hole. While trying to get it out, I think I flicked something that was inside the hole out, and cant find it anymore.  I can just see a bronze/gold plate at the bottom and have no power from it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure you didn't fry the fuse in the process?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Pics or it never happened

Answer (score 1):

All of the 12 V accessory sockets and cigarette lighters that I'm familiar with use a metal shell for the ground side of the jack. There is an insulator at the bottom which separates the shell from the positive terminal in the center. On the plug which goes into the jack there is a clip on the side which contacts the shell.

I think your most likely explanation is the fuse as @Paulster2 suggested in the comment. It would be easy to brush the central contact as you work in the jack and if you were trying to pry you'd very likely be touching the shell at the same time. If you're using a metal tool a single bump is all it would take to blow the fuse.